# 'Sign Up' Error: The setter 'displayName=' was called on null." gets displayed on console. Sign Up button doesn't route to next page

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, mobile-application

The app runs however when clicking the SignUp Button I am not able to go on to the next routed paged. The account does get created as seen from console.firebase, and the only way to go to the next page is to Sign In again with the created credentials.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<String> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(
        (User user) => user?.uid,
      );

  // // GET UID
  // Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
  //   return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  // }

  // Email & Password Sign Up
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    // Update the username
    await updateUserName(name, authResult.user);
    return authResult.user.uid;
  }

  Future updateUserName(String name, User currentUser) async {
    var userUpdateInfo = updateProfile();
        userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
        await currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: userUpdateInfo);
        await currentUser.reload();
      }
    
      // Email & Password Sign In
      Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          String email, String password) async {
        return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password))
            .user
            .uid;
      }
    
      // Sign Out
      signOut() {
        return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
      }
    }
    
    updateProfile() {
}
```

Comment: The error from my understanding is coming from the lines of code after the '// Update the username' comment.

Answer (score 0):

In  **updateUserName** method, the below codes are executed, so try to comment or delete it.

```
      // Sign Out
      signOut() {
        return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
      }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help :/ thank you though.